# want to show notification in status bar after posting notification

Tags: android

i want to show the notification in the status bar after posting the notification from the user. What should i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tutorial for that in the android dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

And the API reference pages are:

Notification: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

PendingIntent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 1):

for notification in status bar...

```
final NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.msg,"New Message",System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,notification.class), 0);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this,"NewMessage","You Receive "+count+" New Message", i);

    mgr.notify(Notify,note);
```